# Using 'CreateViewAccessor.Read' and 'Write'

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to write a type of hex editor (for editing a Playstation 1 ISO), but I'm not sure how to use `CreateViewAccessor.Read` and `Write`. Specifically, I don't know what to use for the second argument, `out T structure`. Here is my code so far:

```
long offset = 0x0064773C;
long length = 0x02;

// Create the memory-mapped file.
using (var mmf =
    MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(strFileName, FileMode.Open, "ISO"))
{
    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            accessor.Read(i, out ???);
        }
    }
}
```

I've never really understood the `out` keyword, so I don't know what to do there...

And if anyone saw my previous post, I decided to use C# and VS instead of C++ and Qt. I know C# much better than C++.

Answer (score 0):

The `Read<>` method is for reading any structure out of the mapping. Here are two equivalent examples - one using the built-in `ReadByte` method, another using the generic `Read<>` method:

```
bytes[i] = accessor.ReadByte(i);
accessor.Read<byte>(i, out bytes[i]);
```

In general, `out` means that the calling method provides the data as output.